# Breakpoints execute in wrong package

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

There are two similar tables that need practically identical treatment. I created one package and then copied it and modified for the second table. Re-generated the ID on both, several times.

They both run fine and do what is expected. Except when I set a break point in the copied package, it executes in the original at the identical spot.

Is there something I need to do after copying a package in addition to changing the ID GUID?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently changing the package ID GUID is not enough. I ended up installing BIDSHelper, which has a "Reset GUIDs" feature that resets GUIDs on every component in the target package.

After running the BIDSHelper GUIDs reset, breakpoints fire where they are supposed to.